# rosdep does not find dist

Tags: rosdep, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I set up rosdep(init, update) and trying to install `python-certifi`. And I allways get the error:

```
root@ros-in-docker:/project# rosdep install python-certifi

ERROR: Rosdep cannot find all required resources to answer your query
Missing resource python-certifi
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/kinetic/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/project/src
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/kinetic/shar
```

But it seems to be in the list for Ubuntu Xenial:

https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/master/rosdep/python.yaml#L870

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/329374/rosdep-does-not-find-dist/) by [julian-r](https://answers.ros.org/users/44309/julian-r/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2019-07-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Afaik `rosdep` only installs the dependencies *of ROS packages*. You cannot use it to install dependencies themselves. `python-certifi` is not a ROS package.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [julian-r](https://answers.ros.org/users/44309/julian-r/) on 2019-07-29**:
Hmm, but [this](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/catkin/html/howto/format1/python_module_dependencies.html) states it differently...

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2019-07-29**:
That's a reference to the xml format used for ros packages and doesn't reflect the command line syntax.